# Meaning of "the broader sth."?

Tags: meaning

The neglect of this important work by **the broader medical community** is little short of unconscionable.

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
the definition/explanation and examples /
grammar rules and examples 
in a dictionary or other trusted reference. For example [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement suggests that that work is appreciated by some narrow segment of the medical community. The "broader community" would mean those in the medical community who are outside the narrow, interested segment. They have neglected the work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack :-)